# Codeigniter populate dropdown value from database based on date selected

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, dropdown

I am not very good with codeigniter and javascript.But I dont even know if this is possible.
Currently I working on dental appointment booking sytem for my final year project.

On the booking function, I have trouble to generate dropdown automatically that will list all the available timeslot based on the date selected by user.

But how do I make it to happen? I have try search some tutorial and question. I do found related answer it something involved with Ajax function but I really not familiar with it, and I am still stuck on it. Have anyone has any idea or any example that I can refer?

Please help me. Thank you :'(

Answer (score 1):

As you have figured out you have to use ajax here. What you can do is use an onchange event listener in your dropdown and do an ajax call with the selected value which would return the required result. How to do it, you hove to find that yourself. Google is your friend.